# How to use slash command in channel with JDA?

Tags: discord-jda

```java
public class HelloWorldBot extends ListenerAdapter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException
    {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("You have to provide a token as first argument!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // args[0] should be the token
        // We don't need any intents for this bot. Slash commands work without any intents!
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createLight(args[0], Collections.emptyList())
                .addEventListeners(new HelloWorldBot())
                .setActivity(Activity.playing("Type /ping"))
                .build();

        jda.upsertCommand("ping", "Calculate ping of the bot").queue(); // This can take up to 1 hour to show up in the client
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlashCommand(SlashCommandEvent event)
    {
        if (!event.getName().equals("ping")) return; // make sure we handle the right command
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        event.reply("Pong!").setEphemeral(true) // reply or acknowledge
                .flatMap(v ->
                        event.getHook().editOriginalFormat("Pong: %d ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - time) // then edit original
                ).queue(); // Queue both reply and edit
    }
}
```

With the code above, I can make use slash command by DM the bot. However, how do I use slash command in a channel?

It says in the discord developer docs that:

> In order to make Slash Commands work within a guild, the guild must
> authorize your application with the applications.commands scope. The
> bot scope is not enough.

How exactly do one do that with JDA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate such an authorization URL you follow these steps:

1. Open your [application dashboard](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Open the tab **OAuth2** after you selected your application
3. Generate an authorization URL with the scopes `bot` and `applications.commands` ticked
4. Copy that URL and open it in a new tab
5. Invite your bot to the guild with that link

Note that, as the comment here correctly points out, the global commands take up to 1 hour to propagate. If you want to test your bot, you can use guild commands which show up instantly.

To create a guild command use `jda.getGuildById(guildId)` to get the guild, then use the same methods for creating commands on that `Guild` instance instead of the `JDA` instance. Note that getting a guild requries for JDA to be ready, so make sure you call `awaitReady()` first after you build your JDA instance.